# Adding a new scaffolded item gives and error "Error log full" in .Net Core Web Application

Tags: asp.net-core, scaffolding

I'm new to .Net Core and I was following Microsoft's tutorial to add a model to my web application from the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

when I try to add a scaffold item after adding a model, I get the following error -

"There was an error running the selected code generator. 'The event log is full'"

Can anybody suggest what might be causing this error?

Comment: Can you clear the event log and try? It might log the error on event log.

Comment: Hi Anuraj, could you please guide me on how exactly can I clear the logs?

Comment: Windows Key + R, type eventvwr. It will open event viewer. Click on expand the windows logs node - Choose right click on Application Logs, select the clear log option, if required take the backup. Follow the same steps for System and security nodes as well.